# dotless dos errorlevel

Tags: dotless

Can anybody help me?

Im trying to use batch file with LESS (dotless.Compiler.exe) and I cannot figure out how this works - I always get 0 for response no matter where there are some errors or not.

Can anybody show me examples how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[this issue](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/51) has been fixed in the latest version.
I will release a new version of dotless (1.2.1) this week that should incorporate the fix.

Until then you can just grab the latest development version and build it yourself.

greetings Daniel